# Return Optional.empty instead of Optional[null] in Optional.map

Tags: java, option-type

In the below code, if `customerInfo` is not present, it returns Optional[null] and hence `customerInfo.get(name).textValue()` returns a NPE. Is there a way to make `map(data -> data.get("customerInfo"))` return `Optional.empty()` instead of `Optional[null]`? Here the null within `Optional[null]` is a NullNode object.

```java
  Optional<JsonNode> orderData = getOrderData() // API Call

  orderData.map(data -> data.get("customerInfo"))
  .map(customerInfo -> customerInfo.get(name).textValue());
```

Comment: That first line is setting the field at numerical index `JsonNode` on a local array variable called `Optional`. It has no relationship to the `Optional` *type* built-in to Java since Java 8. I'm guessing that's not what you *meant* to write, but I'm having trouble filling in the blanks on what was intended there.

Comment: That's not Java.

Comment: `Optional[JsonNode]` is not valid Java, unless `Optional` is an array and `JsonNode` is an int variable. (You are not using the array in your next statement, so it is irrelevant to the question). Also, in Java `Optional.of("something").map(s -> null)` already _is_ an `Optional.empty()` instance.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally mistyped it!When I executed `orderData.map(data -> data.get("customerInfo"))`, I saw Optional[null] in my debugger where null was referencing to NullNode object.

Comment: I thought so. `Optional.ofNullable(null).equals(Optional.empty())` returns `true`.

Comment: @MCEmperor. When I ran Optional.ofNullable(orderData.map(data -> data.get("customerInfo"))) , I see `Optional[Optional[null]]`.

Comment: @ruakh Fixed now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be misinterpreting the problem you're having. The NullPointerException occurs because `customerInfo.get(name)` is null, so `customerInfo.get(name).textValue()` is trying to call the `textValue()` method on a null reference.

To fix this, you can split that call to `map` into *two* calls, like so:

```
orderData.map(data -> data.get("customerInfo"))
  .map(customerInfo -> customerInfo.get(name))
  .map(customer -> customer.textValue());
```

This way, if `customerInfo.get(name)` is null, then the resulting Optional will be empty, and that last lambda won't be executed.